# Processing of Million records using Spring Bach including Pattern Matching

Tags: spring, design-patterns, matching

My use case is as follows:

1) Read 20 Million records from Db2 databse and read the filter criteria from Db2 where it involves with multiple columns and some of the columns has patterns like Column A with value %EMP%.
2) Now for each combination of the rules filter the data on 20M dataset and at the same time update the database column which has a flag indicating this record is filtered out.
3) At the end of the process, we will invoke a Informatica workflow which will take the unfiltered records for 20 M and process it.

We do not want to have the filtering logic on Informatica as it would be expensive so looking for an option to do it using Spring Batch where we can span multiple threads and run the filtering logic.

I am not sure if the Spring Batch is the right candidate for this. But I need some suggestions if I need to implement this on Java.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Camel routes and Spring Boot.

You could use a Camel JPA consumer to place the records on an ActiveMQ queue. Use an JMS consumer with multiple consumers to process the records.

Use an aggregation strategy to invoke your Informatica.

I haven't used Spring Batch so I can't say if its a better solution but Spring Boot and Camel are pretty sweet.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply.  I am looking more info on Camel and Spring Boot as I have not worked on them. Would you please let me know some more information on Camel and Boot